# How to add a route to $resource in AgularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-services

I've this service and I want to add another URL to communicate REST endpoints, for example I want to implement an update for changing lastAccessDateTime property of my current course, using server side DateTime. Can I do that using this service or I've to use a different route definition (courses/:courseId/changedate) in another service?

```
//Courses service used to communicate Courses REST endpoints
angular.module('courses').factory('Courses', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('courses/:courseId',
            {
                courseId: '@_id'
            }, 
            {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to add actions to the resource:

```
angular.module('courses').factory('Courses', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('', { courseId: '@_id' }, { 
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
                url:'courses/:courseId' // this is a override url
            },
            updateWithDate: {
                method: 'PUT', 
                url:'ourses/:courseId/changedate' //override url
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

since you are returning  a resource you can use Courses.update() and Courses.updateWithDate()

Comment: Thanks @jack.the.ripper, I found $resource service documentation for all options https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource